# How to stream JSON objects using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sharepoint

I have created a JSON using rest api in SharePoint

```
function getmovies(url){
 $.ajax({      
    url: url,    
    async: false,    
    type: "GET",   
    headers: {

            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },  
    success: function (data) {
           $.each(data.d.results, function (index, item) {
             var text = '{ "genre": ["'+item.genre.Title+'"],"name":"'+item.Title+'","Actor":"'+item.Actor+'","Director":"'+item.Director+'"}';
             moviejsonobject.push(JSON.parse(text));            
            });        
        }
    });
}
```

moviejsonobject contains more than 5000 items and I am using this to create an html page dynamically.Is there any way to stream the json that is to display items which is passed to the moviejsonobject and rest of the items are loaded in the background.

Like in this url: http://jiren.github.io/filter.js/pagination.html

In the  given url,data_url is passed,which links to an .json file.I cant use a json file in sharepoint.

Comment: Consider the length of the `results` and deal with it in some _chunk_..Do not manipulate `DOM` for all the `results` at a time..

Comment: A couple of questions.  Why are you converting an object to text only to parse it back to a an object?  Do you control the data endpoint? If not, does the api support pagination? There are many ways to accomplish what you want, we just need more information.

Comment: moviesjsonobject is global variable and I am using this for filtering and pagination.I was able to do filtering and pagination using the plugin given the url of  the question.But it is taking a long time during the initial page load since the 5000 items are retrieving.